# Abstract Syntax Tree - Rookie level (Trying to understand)

Tags: syntax, tree, grammar, abstract, abstract-syntax-tree

So I'm trying to learn the AST for the moment and been practicing with some simple functions like

```
var a;
var b;
b = 666
a = b;
print a;
```

which ended like this:
[image: Simple]

so after been trying to understand it. I pretty much starting to understand it but the issue is coming now when i'm trying to do a function like this:

```
var a;
var b;
b = 666;
a = b+42*6;
print a;
```

Where i'm getting trouble is that a=b+42*6 where I don't know how I should make the tree of it. I do know what to do if its only one of them like + or * but not when it's all together. I have been trying to look into youtube clips, tutorials from other sites and so on but couldn't find any similar like that.

So I would need your help guys!

Anyways. I also have a grammar but it would be looking something like in the picture:)

EDIT:

[image: Like this]

I ended up like this. It doesn't feel right...?

EDIT 2:

[image]

Comment: Do the tree exactly as you would calculate it. One part has the multiplication and result of that connects to the addition.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Hmm. Thats the part I don't know really how I would connect. I will paint and edit the post and will let you know how I was thinking.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen There you go. See the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the expression is `a = b + 42 * 6` you have to start by thinking how you would do it yourself. The first part is `42 * 6` based on mathematical rules, so you write that as an expression (using the same terminology you used):

```
    expr
   /  | \
  42  *  6
```

The result of this will be added to `b`, so that's the next one:

```
    expr
   /  | \
   b  +  \
        expr
       /  | \
      42  *  6
```

And then you want to assign it all to `a`, so add that:

```
  assign
 /  |   \
a   =    \
        expr
       /  | \
       b  +  \
            expr
           /  | \
          42  *  6
```

Comment: Ohhh. I didn't knew it it was allowed to use expr twice! Well then it shouldn't be that hard!

Comment: @Thrillofit123 There's no single way to do ASTs, but since you need the result of the previous step to the next you have to combine them somehow.

Comment: I will write down a new picture and send it. If you have the time of course :)? Hold on!

Comment: Done. Its up! What I have to do is just the tree. I haven't been learned to the result yet. This is the longest way we have been learned in school so far:)